TypeError: configSet.processWithEsbuild is not a function when running Jest tests with Angular
I am trying to run my Jest tests for an Angular project, but I'm encountering the following error:
 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: configSet.processWithEsbuild is not a function

    > 1 | import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
        | ^
      2 |

      at NgJestTransformer.process (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/ng-jest-transformer.js:43:23)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:545:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js:5:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/setup.jest.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.886 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\\app\\app.component.spec.ts/i..

What I have tried:
I have already installed jest-preset-angular and have the following in my jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts'],

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '@env/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/environments/$1'
  }
};

I've also tried clearing the node_modules folder and reinstalling dependencies, but the issue persists.
Environment:
Angular Version: 17
Jest Version: 29.7
Has anyone encountered this error before or knows how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated!Has anyone encountered this error before or knows how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated!

Maybe it does not have support for es-build, try this suggestion from TypeError: configSet.processWithEsbuild is not a function
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts'],

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular' // <- changed here!
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '@env/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/environments/$1'
  }
};


This changes in working for only in App.component not for the child component. For child component it again the same issue

@BaisakhiPanda please share a stackblitz or github repo, where the issue happens, so that I can check it
